# A glitch in 2.71, My low poly model randomly flattened

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, mirror, coordinates

So I was working on a low poly model, A Guy Fawkes mask as an easter egg for a game.  The game will use Unity, but that is besides the point. I had finished this model, so on a different layer I had made Newton's Flaming Laser Sword, or Adler's razor as another easter egg. I had added a basic particle system to it and wanted to render it out so I had saved that file and opened a new one.  I appended the sword and flame particle system in and rendered it out.  When I deleted out that file I returned to my easter eggs file and found my model squashed onto the x and y axis.  All the z values are the same and I really do not want to have to re-do it.  It is on 2.71, I have yet to update it and sadly  am working on a Mac.  Thanks for any help.
[image: Flat Fawkes]

Comment: look for backup file they end with .blend1 .blend2 ..

Comment: I just checked those files, but it is flattened in both. Thanks for trying @Chebhou.

Comment: In addition to that file not being any different, I can not move any of the vertices on the z axis.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: If you can't move vertices on the Z axis, then this might indicate your object has scale set to 0 on that axis.